# The probability

Tags: probability

The probability that I have to wait at the traffic lights on my way to school is 0.25. Find the probability that ,on two consecutive mornings,I have to wait on at least one morning.

Comment: Is "The probability" really the most useful question title you can come up with?

Answer (score 3):

The probability that on a certain day, you don't have to wait is $$1-\frac14=\frac34$$

So, the probability that on two consecutive mornings, you don't have to wait at all is $$\left(\frac34\right)^2=\frac9{16}$$

So, the probability that on two consecutive mornings, you have to wait on at least one morning is $$1-\frac9{16}=\frac7{16}$$

---

Alternatively, if $W$ represents waiting and $N$ represents no wait,

the probability of waiting is $P(W)=\frac14$ and
the probability of not waiting $P(N)=1-\frac14=\frac34$

Hence,  our required probability is  $$P(W)P(N)+P(W)P(W)+P(N)P(W)=\frac14\frac34+\frac14\frac14+\frac34\frac14=\frac{3+1+3}{16}=\frac7{16}$$

Comment: Why is the probability of not having to wait two mornings in a row the square of the probability of not having to wait on any given morning?

Comment: What is probability of throwing two heads in two throw of one a single unbiased coin?

Comment: "What is probability of throwing two heads in two throw of one a single unbiased coin?" You tell me; I don't know. There is the assumption of independent trials which needs to be made, and this is much more easy to justify in my mind when talking of coin tosses than the corresponding assumption about having to wait at traffic lights on two successive mornings. To put it another way, please edit your answer to at least mention that you are assuming independence of the events on two successive mornings.

Comment: How can the waiting on two successive mornings be dependent on each other?

Comment: How can two successive tosses of a coin be independent or even have the same probability of turning up heads? Physically, the coin is _slightly_ different because a few atoms have been knocked off when it landed on the first round, and so the probability of Heads on the second toss depends on the outcome of the first toss. Modeling all this in the mathematical theory is difficult, and it is easier to make _assumptions_ that lead to answers that match observations. And it is better if these were stated up front. (More)

Comment: I remember reading about a (Danish?) mathematician who, as a prisoner-of-war in WWII, actually tossed a coin a large number of times and recorded the results. After thousands of tosses, the coin was so beat up that it was hard to tell the sides apart.

Comment: The waiting on two successive mornings can be dependent, for example, if things are rigidly scheduled.  If you leave the house at the same time every morning, the light is red for 2.75 minutes, then green for 8.25 minutes, the time it goes red advances one minute per day.  Successive days are then correlated.